# How to neglect timestamps when inserting date to MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python, mysql-connector-python

I want to insert a date into MySQL table. But, even if I use `strftime()`, the timestamps are showing like `00:00:00`. How can I get rid of it?

```py
insert_stmt = (
    "insert into dates (Date)"
    "values (%s)"
)

date = datetime.date(2020, 4, 6)
formatted_date = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

data = (formatted_date,)
mycursor.execute(insert_stmt, data)
mydb.commit()
```

Output:

```sql
mysql> select * from dates;
+---------------------+------+
| Date                | name |
+---------------------+------+
| 2020-03-23 00:00:00 | John |
| 2020-03-03 00:00:00 | NULL |
| 2020-04-06 00:00:00 | NULL |
+---------------------+------+
3 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

Comment: The filed Date is a datetime field in mysql, you need to select `SELECT DATE(<Date_field>) FROM dates;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously the column `Date` has data type `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`.
If you don't need the time part of the column, you should change the data type to `DATE`:

```
ALTER TABLE dates MODIFY Date DATE;
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem has nothing to do with python, once you insert a date in a datetime field in mysql it will append time and seconds as 0 automatically.

You want to select date field like so:

`SELECT DATE(Date), name FROM dates;`

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the column as datatype TEXT if you want to retain a specific format.

`Create table dates ( Date TEXT,  name TEXT )`

strftime is anyway converting to a string, anyway.

Or DATE, if you just want to get rid of the time stamp.
`Create table dates ( Date DATE,  name TEXT )`

in this case you don't need to convert the datetime object to string. It will cast into the target datatype by itself.